# Select with CASE Statement SQL Server 2008 R2

Tags: sql, sql-server-2008, select, case

I have a query that uses a `CASE` statement to score accounts. The query looks for values that are in a vector form. So for instance if I am a patient I can have multiple diagnosis codes, but they are not stored as column values, they are stored in another row like so:

```
VISIT_ID | CLASFCD
123      | 196.0
123      | 197.0
123      | 198.0
321      | 199.0
321      | 650.9
222      | 111
555      | ...
...
```

My query uses a Case Statment like so:

```
, CASE
    WHEN DV.ClasfCd IN (
    '196.0','196.1','196.2','196.3','196.5','196.6','196.8','196.9',
    '197.0','197.1','197.2','197.3','197.4','197.5','197.6','197.7',
    '197.8','198.2','198.3','198.4','198.5','199.1','209.7'
    )
    THEN 6
    ELSE 0
  END AS PRIN_DX_CD_5
```

I do this for 5 different groups of codes. What's happening is that if the criteria is met for one of those groups, the results come back in another row instead of on the same row.  Here is an example of the data that I am getting back:

```
VISIT_ID | CC GROUP 1 | CC GROUP 2 | CC GROUP 3 | CC GROUP 4 | CC GROUP 5 | TOTAL
123      | 1          | 0          | 0          | 0          | 0          | 1
123      | 0          | 2          | 0          | 0          | 0          | 2
123      | 0          | 0          | 0          | 0          | 0          | 0
```

What I want returned is the following:

```
VISIT_ID | CC GROUP 1 | CC GROUP 2 | CC GROUP 3 | CC GROUP 4 | CC GROUP 5 | TOTAL
123      | 1          | 2          | 0          | 0          | 0          | 3
321      | 1          | 0          | 0          | 0          | 6          | 6
```

***The final total score cannot exceed 6.***

The entire query in some brevity is here, it is part of a multi-part query, I am making changes to the original:

```
SET ANSI_NULLS OFF
GO
DECLARE @SD DATETIME
DECLARE @ED DATETIME
SET @SD = '2013-01-01';
SET @ED = '2013-05-31';

-- @CM TABLE DECLARATION #############################################]
DECLARE @CM TABLE (
ENCOUNTER_ID VARCHAR(200)
, [MRN CM] VARCHAR(200)
, NAME VARCHAR(500)
, [CC GRP ONE SCORE] VARCHAR(20)
, [CC GRP TWO SCORE] VARCHAR(20)
, [CC GRP THREE SCORE] VARCHAR(20)
, [CC GRP FOUR SCORE] VARCHAR(20)
, [CC GRP FIVE SCORE] VARCHAR(20)
, [CC LACE SCORE] INT
)
--####################################################################]

INSERT INTO @CM
SELECT
C.PT_NO
, C.MED_REC_NO
, C.PT_NAME
, C.PRIN_DX_CD_1
, C.PRIN_DX_CD_2
, C.PRIN_DX_CD_3
, C.PRIN_DX_CD_4
, C.PRIN_DX_CD_5
, CASE
    WHEN (C.PRIN_DX_CD_1+C.PRIN_DX_CD_2+C.PRIN_DX_CD_3+C.PRIN_DX_CD_4+C.PRIN_DX_CD_5) = 0 THEN 0
    WHEN (C.PRIN_DX_CD_1+C.PRIN_DX_CD_2+C.PRIN_DX_CD_3+C.PRIN_DX_CD_4+C.PRIN_DX_CD_5) = 1 THEN 1
    WHEN (C.PRIN_DX_CD_1+C.PRIN_DX_CD_2+C.PRIN_DX_CD_3+C.PRIN_DX_CD_4+C.PRIN_DX_CD_5) = 2 THEN 2
    WHEN (C.PRIN_DX_CD_1+C.PRIN_DX_CD_2+C.PRIN_DX_CD_3+C.PRIN_DX_CD_4+C.PRIN_DX_CD_5) = 3 THEN 3
    WHEN (C.PRIN_DX_CD_1+C.PRIN_DX_CD_2+C.PRIN_DX_CD_3+C.PRIN_DX_CD_4+C.PRIN_DX_CD_5) = 4 THEN 4
    WHEN (C.PRIN_DX_CD_1+C.PRIN_DX_CD_2+C.PRIN_DX_CD_3+C.PRIN_DX_CD_4+C.PRIN_DX_CD_5) = 5 THEN 5
    WHEN (C.PRIN_DX_CD_1+C.PRIN_DX_CD_2+C.PRIN_DX_CD_3+C.PRIN_DX_CD_4+C.PRIN_DX_CD_5) >= 6 THEN 6
  END AS CC_LACE_SCORE

FROM (
    SELECT DISTINCT PAV.PT_NO
    , MED_REC_NO
    , PT_NAME
    , CASE
        WHEN dv.ClasfCd IN (

        )
        THEN 1
        ELSE 0
      END AS PRIN_DX_CD_1
    , CASE
        WHEN DV.ClasfCd IN (

        )
        THEN 2
        ELSE 0
    END AS PRIN_DX_CD_2
    , CASE
        WHEN DV.ClasfCd IN (

        )
        THEN 3
        ELSE 0
      END AS PRIN_DX_CD_3
    , CASE
        WHEN DV.ClasfCd IN (

        )
        THEN 4
        ELSE 0
      END AS PRIN_DX_CD_4
    , CASE
        WHEN DV.ClasfCd IN (

        )
        THEN 6
        ELSE 0
      END AS PRIN_DX_CD_5

      FROM smsdss.BMH_PLM_PtAcct_V PAV
      JOIN smsdss.BMH_PLM_PtAcct_Clasf_Dx_V DV
      ON PAV.PtNo_Num = DV.PtNo_Num

      WHERE Dsch_Date BETWEEN @SD AND @ED


)C

GROUP BY C.PT_NO
, C.MED_REC_NO
, C.PT_NAME
, C.PRIN_DX_CD_1
, C.PRIN_DX_CD_2
, C.PRIN_DX_CD_3
, C.PRIN_DX_CD_4
, C.PRIN_DX_CD_5
ORDER BY C.Pt_No

SELECT * FROM @CM
```

thank you for your help,

Comment: Have you looked into the `PIVOT` command? http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms177410.aspx

Comment: @DarrenKopp i have never used the `PIVOT` command. Would using that prevent me from taking values from it a query that follows it?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The problem is that you are including the calculated `PRIN_DX_` columns in the aggregation.  Instead, remove them from the aggregation and just choose the non-0 value (using `max()`):

```
SELECT C.PT_NO, C.MED_REC_NO, C.PT_NAME,
       max(C.PRIN_DX_CD_1) as PRIN_DX_CD_1,
       max(C.PRIN_DX_CD_2) as PRIN_DX_CD_2,
       max(C.PRIN_DX_CD_3) as PRIN_DX_CD_3,
       max(C.PRIN_DX_CD_4) as PRIN_DX_CD_4,
       max(C.PRIN_DX_CD_5) as PRIN_DX_CD_5,
       (case when max(C.PRIN_DX_CD_1) + max(C.PRIN_DX_CD_2) + max(C.PRIN_DX_CD_3) + 
                  max(C.PRIN_DX_CD_4) + max(C.PRIN_DX_CD_5) < 6
             then max(C.PRIN_DX_CD_1) + max(C.PRIN_DX_CD_2) + max(C.PRIN_DX_CD_3) + 
                  max(C.PRIN_DX_CD_4) + max(C.PRIN_DX_CD_5)
             else 6
        end) as CC_LACE_SCORE
FROM (SELECT DISTINCT PAV.PT_NO, MED_REC_NO, PT_NAME,
             (CASE WHEN dv.ClasfCd IN ()
                   THEN 1
                   ELSE 0
              END) AS PRIN_DX_CD_1,
             (CASE WHEN DV.ClasfCd IN ()
                   THEN 2
                   ELSE 0
              END) AS PRIN_DX_CD_2
             (CASE WHEN DV.ClasfCd IN ()
                   THEN 3
                   ELSE 0
              END) AS PRIN_DX_CD_3,
             (CASE WHEN DV.ClasfCd IN ()
                   THEN 4
                   ELSE 0
              END) AS PRIN_DX_CD_4,
             (CASE WHEN DV.ClasfCd IN ()
                   THEN 6
                   ELSE 0
              END) AS PRIN_DX_CD_5   
      FROM smsdss.BMH_PLM_PtAcct_V PAV join
           smsdss.BMH_PLM_PtAcct_Clasf_Dx_V DV
           ON PAV.PtNo_Num = DV.PtNo_Num
      WHERE Dsch_Date BETWEEN @SD AND @ED
     ) C
GROUP BY C.PT_NO, C.MED_REC_NO, C.PT_NAME
ORDER BY C.Pt_No;
```

I suspect the `distinct` in the subquery may not be necessary, but that depends on what your data really looks like.

Comment: This update gets all scores on the same line, which is great, but for some reason the total column uses the maximum score of what is in the columns, it does not give a sum of the scores stopping at 6. Example of what returned:
Gropu 1 = 1, Group 2 = 2, Total = 2, should be 3, a little confused as to why it did not work.

Comment: That seems to have fixed it.  Thank you Gordon

Answer (score 1):

UPDATE:

- MSDN [PIVOT](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms177410%28SQL.105%29.aspx)
- MSDN [FUNCTION](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms186755%28v=SQL.105%29.aspx) , TECHNET [FUNCTION](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa258261%28v=SQL.80%29.aspx)
- MSDN [APPLY](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms175156%28v=sql.105%29.aspx) - check cross apply statement

You defenitly need to look into pivot as @Darren Kopp says

Create table to map your values in `IN` clauses with groups

Then do pivot

Then simpify your case when to  `minimum(val, 6)` using something like

```
CREATE FUNCTION Minimum
(@Param1 Integer, @Param2 Integer)
Returns Table As
Return(Select Case When @Param1 < @Param2 
               Then @Param1 Else @Param2 End MinValue)
```

So your table cdmap would be

```
6    |    '196.0'
6    |    '196.1'
6    |    '196.2'


SELECT ....,  [1], [2], [4], [6]
FROM
(
FROM smsdss.BMH_PLM_PtAcct_V PAV
  JOIN smsdss.BMH_PLM_PtAcct_Clasf_Dx_V DV
  ON PAV.PtNo_Num = DV.PtNo_Num
  JOIN cdmap c on c.ClasfCd = dv.ClasfCd
  WHERE Dsch_Date BETWEEN @SD AND @ED
 ) AS SourceTable
 PIVOT
 (
  ...
  FOR c.ClasfCd IN ([1], [2], [4], [6])
 ) AS PivotTable;
```

Comment: Would you be able to provide a link to good documentation on creating a function? I have never done that either, I have not been using SQL for even a year yet and it's all self taught so I am sure to have some really bad practices and I do not know many ways to simplify code and optimize it.

Comment: gave you some links. added part of pivot query to start with, try to finish it yourself. also check what cross/outer apply is.

Comment: Thank you for all the links, it will be very helpful for me in the future, my school semester ends sunday when I hand in my final exam, so this will make for good winter reading.